# Oracle partition key

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I have many tables with large amount of data. The PK is the column (`TAB_ID`) which has data type `RAW(16)`. I created the hash partitions with partition key having the `TAB_ID` column.

My issue is: the SQL statement (`select * from my_table where tab_id = 'aas1df'`) does not use partition pruning.  If I change the column datatype to `varchar2(32)`, partition pruning works.

Why does not partition pruning work with partition key which have datatype `RAW(16)`?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `RAW(16)`? (especially for a PK column) What are you storing in that column? Why can't you use an integer (or at least a varchar).

Comment: The database was development by another team. The database is in production and I will try to improve its performance.
The tab_id keep unique value for many platforms and can not be numeric now (maybe for future). Tab_id look like ROWID() .
E.g: 
3334646B6A5533AA430C17FF1EC6FE6A
06A0D84EEE12B3A6DB75F5F5204D53D2
02D22D02BCF64CC8CA6F59546BF1D303
57BF0DC18DEC9AB991FDE44572D868D4

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing: try `select * from my_table where 'aas1df' = tab_id`. 
Probably the datatype conversion works other way that expected. Anyway you should use the function UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW.

Edited:
Is your table partitioned by `TAB_ID`? If yes, then there is something wrong with your design, you usually partition table by some useful business value, NOT by surrogate key.
If you know the PK value you do not need partition pruning at all. When Oracle traverses the PK index it gets ROWID value. This ROWID contains file-number, block ID and also row number within the block. So Oracle can access directly the row.

Comment: Thank you. I used the function in my statement but in the plan execution in Pstart and Pstop are displaying RAWID , not partiton number. I don't know what means this. 

explain plan for select * from JOHN.U_TEST where TAB_ID = UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('0662A5A92215C8DF03');
 select * from table (dbms_xplan.display)

Comment: Plan hash value: 1914993806
 

| Id  | Operation                          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |           |     1 |   112 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| U_TEST    |     1 |   112 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | ROWID | ROWID |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | U_TEST_PK |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |

Comment: There *are* valid reasons to (hash) partition by a generated number, e.g. to avoid contention on "nearby" rows in the same block

Answer (score 0):

[`HEXTORAW`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions073.htm#SQLRF00649) enables partition pruning.

In the sample below the Pstart and Pstop are literal numbers, implying partition pruning occurs.

```
create table my_table
(
    TAB_ID raw(16),
    a number,
    constraint my_table_pk primary key (tab_id)
)
partition by hash(tab_id) partitions 16;

explain plan for
select *
from my_table
where tab_id = hextoraw('1BCDB0E06E7C498CBE42B72A1758B432');

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic +partition'));

Plan hash value: 1204448714

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name        | Pstart| Pstop |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |             |       |       |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| MY_TABLE    |     2 |     2 |
|   2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | MY_TABLE_PK |       |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot modify all statements for add the function hextoraw.

Comment: @JohnnyM. If neither the tables nor the statements can be modified there aren't many options.  One possibility is to set CURSOR_SHARING=FORCE to force all plans with literals to look the same and then use DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE to automatically convert the statements to use HEXTORAW.  Is that what you want?  If not, what kind of solution are you looking for?